# PHP Notice error: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in (testing for mySQL8)

Tags: php, boolean

I am testing for the MySQL update and am seeing these errors. The plugin is up to date on my site.

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /Users/janetaylor/Local Sites/kirschcpagroup/app/public/wp-content/plugins/option-tree/includes/class-ot-settings.php on line 395
> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /Users/janetaylor/Local Sites/kirschcpagroup/app/public/wp-content/plugins/option-tree/includes/class-ot-settings.php on line 396:

```
/\*\*
\* Adds sections to the page
\*
\* @return bool
\*
\* @access public
\* @since  2.0
\*/
public function add_sections() {

    // Loop through options.
    foreach ( (array) $this->options as $option ) {

        // Loop through pages.
        foreach ( (array) $this->get_pages( $option ) as $page ) {

            // Loop through page sections.
            foreach ( (array) $this->get_sections( $page ) as $section ) {

                // Add each section.
                add_settings_section(
                    $section['id'],
                    $section['title'],
                    array( $this, 'display_section' ),
                    $page['menu_slug']
                );

            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The error is on lines: `$section['id'], $section['title'],`

I have very limited PHP knowledge, so any help is appreciated!

I have not tried anything yet

Comment: The error means that `$section` is `true` or `false`, not an array. So `$this->get_sections($page)` is returning an array of true/false values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So how do I resolve this?

Comment: I have no idea. It's your data, you need to figure out why it has unexpected values.

Comment: If this came from SQL queries, I suspect you're not checking whether the query succeeded before saving the results.

Comment: Bear with me, I have no previous SQL experience so I'm not sure what you mean by checking whether the query succeeded. Could you explain that process?

Comment: It's hard to be specific without seeing your code that makes the SQL query and processes the results. But if you do something like `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` you should check that `$row` is not false before saving it in the array.

Comment: I can show you that code I just need to understand where to find it - is that the plugin's code? Or something else?

Comment: How should I know? I didn't even know you were using a plugin.

Comment: It seems like you don't even know enough to be able to debug your own code. You need to find a programmer to help you, I can't walk you through this in comments.